# Help identify playing cards

Tags: part-identification

I'd like to design a poker scene similar to [this one](http://bricksplosion.com/lego-poker-im-all-in/):

[image]

I've been able to find some individual cards such as [the joker](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb338&name=Tile%201%20X%202%20with%20Groove%20with%20Playing%20Card%20Joker%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=1).  However, I can't find the full 'hand' piece in the bottom right. Is that a real LEGO?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are all  the playing card tiles I can find:

[3069bpb264 : Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Playing Cards Four Aces Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpb264&in=S)

[image]

[3069bpx6 : Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Playing Cards Full House Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpx6&in=S)
[image]

[3069bpb337: Tile 1 X 2 with Groove with Playing Card Ace of Spades Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb337&name=Tile%201%20X%202%20with%20Groove%20with%20Playing%20Card%20Ace%20of%20Spades%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C)
[image]

[3069bpb338 : Tile 1 X 2 with Groove with Playing Card Joker Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb338&name=Tile%201%20X%202%20with%20Groove%20with%20Playing%20Card%20Joker%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=1)

[image]

Those last two part numbers are individual cards, both of which came from a Jester minifigure from one of the collectible minifigs series.

Also, those coins you see in the middle of the table are from part 70501c01 and  97053.

Comment: Side note: somebody in this game is definitely cheating, since there's 2 Aces of Spades on the table...